# How to write a gtsummary with CI and overall column in last column

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to write a summary with confidence intervals for categorical variables and an overall column at the end of the table.

However using the following code, the overall column is placed at the front:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    include = "stage") %>%
  add_overall(last = TRUE)%>% 
  add_ci()
```

Why is the overall column at the beginning, even though I set `last = TRUE`?
[image: Overall column in the front]

Comment: The add_ci() has some complex rearranging of columns. Try running add_overall() last?

Comment: If I run add_overall() last, there is no CI for the overall group. Guess, I'll have to rearrange the columns later in a tibble. Thanks anyways!

Comment: ah of course. i didn't review the post closely enough, apologies. see below for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below for a solution to re-order columns in a gtsummary table.

```r
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    include = "stage") %>%
  add_overall(last = TRUE) %>%
  add_ci() %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~dplyr::relocate(.x, stat_0, ci_stat_0, .after = last_col() )
  ) %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **95% CI** | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **95% CI** | **Overall**, N = 200 | **95% CI** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T Stage |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| T1 | 28 (29%) | 20%, 39% | 25 (25%) | 17%, 34% | 53 (27%) | 21%, 33% |
| T2 | 25 (26%) | 17%, 35% | 29 (28%) | 20%, 38% | 54 (27%) | 21%, 34% |
| T3 | 22 (22%) | 15%, 32% | 21 (21%) | 13%, 30% | 43 (22%) | 16%, 28% |
| T4 | 23 (23%) | 16%, 33% | 27 (26%) | 18%, 36% | 50 (25%) | 19%, 32% |

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I filed a bug report with gtsummary here https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1525